# How to capture file downloaded as a result of cross domain post request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

1. I can not use Ajax because I do not have access to the third party server
2. File download starts automatically after submitting the form
3. I want to import this file (it's a CSV) into an array, but for that I need to somehow capture it

All examples that I researched are showing capture of a response to an AJAX call, which I can not use due to CORS.

Current code includes a post form, and a submit function.

This does not work due to CORS constraints:

```
 $('#f1')
.ajaxForm({
    url : $('#f1').attr('action'), 
    type: 'post',
    dataType : 'document',
    crossDomain: true,
    success : function (response) {
        alert("The server says: " + response);
    }
})
```

This of course works but file is downloaded to the filesystem:

```
 $('#f1').submit()
```

I need to somehow extract the attachment from the post reponse and load it into a variable.

Comment: So either **(a)** request the file from your server and then use your server to request the file from the other server, before finally returning it to the browser (from _your_ server). or **(b)** get the user to pick the downloaded file and then load it's contents and finally, use them just like you would if you'd got them via ajax.

Comment: How would you go about sending a request to the server and then fulfilling it? I have no server side coding experience

Comment: I'd be using PHP and would simply call `file_get_contents`, followed by using `echo` to produce an output. Basically, I'd be using code of the form shown in example #1 here: `http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php` Except, you'd also have to process the form's fields and pass them onto the external server. You can look at the request headers your browser generates and clone the fields that are important. You'd need to pass them in the manner discussed in Example #4 of the above link. You may like to look into the `FileReader` object and the method `.readAsDataUrl` as easier.